# How to advance in a queue with 8-bit members and combine couples into 16-bit values

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation

I have a pointer to an array holding ,say, four pair of 8-bit values such as this

```
MSB-lsb-MSB-lsb-MSB-lsb-MSB-lsb
 ^
 |
bufPointer
```

I am going to advance in this queue and populate the `fooStruct` structure's 16-bit members with these four 8-bit couples.

I can do this in two lines as below for the 1st member:

```
fooStruct.M1 = *bufPointer << 8;
fooStruct.M1 |= *++bufPointer;
```

and so on.

So, if we had

```
MSB = 0x22;
lsb = 0x37;
hence => fooStrct.M1 = 0x2237;
```

Is it possible to do this in a one liner ?

---

*Why One-Liner ?*
No special reason really. To learn + curiosity / future use if convenient. :)

Comment: Did you by any chance learn Perl before C? ;)

Comment: @paddy Why ? :) or better way to say HOW!!!

Comment: It was just a jibe at the fact that Perl programmers have a tendency to write as much of a program as possible in one line, even if it makes the program unmaintainable...  *Especially* if it makes the program unmaintainable!

Comment: I would say abbreviating and compacting the code doesn't always have a bad effect and in some situations it's a plus. Some occasions more readable since you see the working block in a page and a glance. But this case is only curiosity as I couldn't figure it out and couldn't get over it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it in a one liner, but to avoid sequence point warnings, it may be best done like:

```
c = (*p << 8) | *(p + 1);
```

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#if defined(__LP64__) || defined(_LP64)
# define BUILD_64   1
#endif

#ifdef BUILD_64
# define BITS_PER_LONG 64
#else
# define BITS_PER_LONG 32
#endif

char *binpad (unsigned long n, size_t sz);

int main (void) {

    unsigned char a[] = { 65, 28, 59, 15 };
    unsigned char *p = NULL;
    unsigned char *end = a + sizeof a/sizeof *a;

    unsigned short c = 0;

    for (p = a; p < end; p += 2)
    {
        c = (*p << 8) | *(p + 1);

        printf ("\n *p       : %6hhu  (%s)\n", *p, binpad (*p, 16));
        printf (" *(p + 1) : %6hhu  (%s)\n", *(p + 1), binpad (*(p + 1), 16));
        printf ("\n c        : %6hu  (%s)\n", c, binpad (c, 16));
    }

    return 0;
}

char *binpad (unsigned long n, size_t sz)
{
    static char s[BITS_PER_LONG + 1] = {0};
    char *p = s + BITS_PER_LONG;
    register size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        *(--p) = (n>>i & 1) ? '1' : '0';

    return p;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/uchar2short

 *p       :     65  (0000000001000001)
 *(p + 1) :     28  (0000000000011100)

 c        :  16668  (0100000100011100)

 *p       :     59  (0000000000111011)
 *(p + 1) :     15  (0000000000001111)

 c        :  15119  (0011101100001111)
```

Comment: That `"+1"` rather than `"++"` deserves a *+1* :)

Answer (score 1):

Why is doing it in one line so important?

Anyway, this is one way:

```
fooStruct.M1 = (bufPointer += 2, (bufPointer[-2] << 8) | bufPointer[-1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can do it in one line.  But I would question why, because invariably code becomes less readable when it is crammed into fewer lines.  The compiler does not care whether you do it in one or several.

<strike>The most readable one-liner, I think, is to increment each time:</strike>

```
fooStruct.M1 = (*bufPointer++ << 8) | *bufPointer++;
```

But some may argue against this.

[Note the above is removed, as per comments below.  Bad advice from me!  Other answers contain one-liners that avoid sequence point problems]

My personal coding style is to make it clear that I'm addressing a single record and using pieces of it:

```
fooStruct.M1 = (bufPointer[0] << 8) | bufPointer[1];
bufPointer += 2;
```

But of course that is two lines...  Any compiler worth its salt ought to generate the same assembly for these two variations.

---

Just editing after the fact...  Reading between the lines in your answer, I'm guessing that you want this code to be compact because you are assigning separate struct elements and can't do this in a loop.  In that case:

```
fooStruct.M1 = (bufPointer[0] << 8) | bufPointer[1];
fooStruct.M2 = (bufPointer[2] << 8) | bufPointer[3];
fooStruct.M3 = (bufPointer[4] << 8) | bufPointer[5];
fooStruct.M4 = (bufPointer[6] << 8) | bufPointer[7];
bufPointer += 8;  // Only if you need to keep deserialising
```

Comment: `(*bufPointer++ << 8) | *bufPointer++;` / *"some may argue against this"* - it's *undefined behaviour* as you're modifying `bufPointer` twice with no sequencing.

Comment: Thanks @TonyD, I am usually on top of my undefined behaviours, but I didn't realise this was one.  Now I'm paranoid about production code I may have written in the past containing that style, and I will add it to my mental list of red-flags for code reviews.  I will remove that bit from my answer.

Comment: and also the results end up being 0xlsb-MSB rather than oxMSB-lsb :)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using C++ you could wrap the buffer in a smarter "reader".

```
class Reader
{
public:
    Reader(char* bufPointer)
        : m_bufPointer(bufPointer) {}

    short shortBE()
    {
        short result = (m_bufPointer[0] << 8) | m_bufPointer[1];
        m_bufPointer += 2;
        return result;
    }

    short shortLE()
    {
        short result = (m_bufPointer[1] << 8) | m_bufPointer[0];
        m_bufPointer += 2;
        return result;
    }

    // etc...
};


FooStruct DeserializeFooStruct(char* bufPointer)
{
   Reader rd(bufPointer);

   FooStruct fooStruct;
   fooStruct.M1 = rd.shortBE();
   fooStruct.M2 = rd.shortBE();
   // and so on
   return fooStruct;
}
```

One advantage of this approach is that you can also add error checking. For example, if you carry the length of the buffer along you could check make sure that no code tries to read past the end of the buffer and still keep it a one-liner for the caller.

Comment: Just curious. What does *BE* and *LE* stand for and where you'll be planing use *LE*?

Comment: Big-endian and little-endian. I was just using LE for illustration.

Answer (score 0):

Small variation on the accepted answer:

```
c = (p[0] << 8) | p[1];
```

If you were on a big-endian machine and either your data was aligned at 16-bit boundary or unaligned access was supported, then you could simply:

```
c = *(short*)p;
```